# Почему приложение с JavaFX ест очень много ОЗУ?

Tags: javafx

Создал небольшое простенькое приложение на Java с использованием JavaFX - окошко с парой кнопок, textArea и textField. При запуске приложения, практически никаких действий не происходит. Создаю в Intellij IDEA 12.1.4, на Win7/64 Ultimate. Комп: Intel Core i3-2310M, ОЗУ - 4ГБ. При запуске программы, приложение съедает 50-55 МБ. На работе 40-45 (Intel Dual 2.3 ГГц, 4 ГБ, Win7/32 Ultimate). Тот же GUI на Swing-е съедает 15-18 МБ. Такая проблема с JavaFX стандартна и приемлема? Версия JRE последняя.

Comment: Наверно это не проблема,а tradeoff.

Comment: нужно меньше памяти - используйте другие способы. Java (и все, что на ее базе построено) закладывается на то, что память будет тратиться.

Но может с этих 50 Мб памяти половина пустует (jvm выделила немного памяти себе с запасом - абсолютно нормально), а треть памяти занимает "красивая jpeg картинка для заставки"...